# How to convert boot mode from legacy boot to UEFI boot??

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

my pc is dell inspiron 5537... partion style is MBR. Setup mode is legacy with SECURE boot OFF.when I acsess boot manager and change boot mode to uefi boot with SECURE boot ON... There will be no boot device

Comment: Why change from legacy to UEFI? Is there any advantage?

Answer (score 0):

You can of course switch from Legacy format to a UFEI boot format.

The problem is that you have to basically reformat your disk (with the loss of all partitions and their contents) to do it.  This includes reinstalling the OS and all the applications.  Possibly taking a fair amount of time.

Also, are you sure your BIOS boots in the newer boot format?

Basically the underlying disk partitioning scheme allows for disks > 22TB and for many more partitions than the legacy type.